# JS Hello Week "ReferenceError: HelloWeek is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I want to use this library : https://hello-week.vercel.app/

I'm having a hard time to understand how to use it. I know JS and I never used Typescript or Nodejs. I found the .js and .css of this library but it's seems not to work
"calendar.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWeek is not defined"

Can I included like a normal js file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the basic usage in the [Installation](https://hello-week.vercel.app/#/docs/v2/installation) page of the docs. Just ensure to reference `hello.week.min.js`, `hello.week.min.css` and `hello.week.theme.min.css`. Typescript or Node.JS don't seem to be necessary.

Here is a quick HTML + JS example:

```
<link href="hello.week.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="hello.week.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="calendar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.week.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new HelloWeek({
      selector: '.calendar'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, are you sure this is normal Javascript syntax ?
Console error :
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: `new Hello Week` is not valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the installation guide is not really clear, here is how to get it done:

First of all this line is simply wrong

```
new Hello Week({
```

There should not be a space there, do this instead

```
new HelloWeek({
```

Also, you will need the language file. Ether host it in its particular directory hierarchy or use the langFolder option to specify where it is.

dist

-- langs

-- -- en.json

Finally, this dose not work when not in a server due to a CORS issue. Serve the files through a server and you will have it working.